# Entity framework 6.0.1 -> 6.1 update, project references say "6.0.0.0"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I've updated my solution to use EF 6.1 using `Library Package Manager`

Next I've reviewed the list of pending changes and EF reference in each project resembles these lines:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Why does it specifies `Version=6.0.0.0` in fully qualified name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EntityFramework `6.1.0` still has an Assembly Version of `6.0.0.0` to make upgrades easier from NuGet package `6.0.0` to `6.1.0` so that you don't need a binding redirect in your configuration file.

What's in your `.csproj` for the `Include` attribute value on the reference is correct.

Comment: any trusted link on EF about this topic?

Comment: You can see here in the EntityFramework source code: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/SharedAssemblyVersionInfo.cs.

Comment: On EntityFramework `6.1.3` this is happening the same. Thanks!